# Error: An unhandled win32 exception occurred in Uplay.exe

Tags: windows, steam, exceptions

I was trying to install a game, I payed for it on Steam, downloaded it, installed it and then when I tried to run it, it gave me an error, that Ubisoft Game Launcher couldn't be found.

I made a little research and found some steps to do that did the work for others:

> Start → `cmd` → `regedit`
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Ubisoft`
>
> They are named `Launcher`, DELETE THEM.

That's what I found and what I did. Then after that I installed the game launcher again. When I try to run the game again another error now comes up:

[image: Error]

So again I did some research and saw that probably that error comes up because of the files I deleted previously. I don't know if I deleted something that I shouldn't or something like that...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a whole lot about the registry, but what I do know is that you should always be careful when you work with it. The registry lacks a lot of fail-saves that the normal windows processes DO possess.

With that being said you can try to do 2 things.

1. If you have a back-up, you should use that. If you don't then let this be a lesson for the future. ALWAYS make a back-up of your registry if you are messing with it.
2. You could try to do a system restore. This will set a lot of things back to how they were in a previous time (you will keep everything on your hard-drive). If the normal system restore doesn't work you can try to restore your windows using the windows software (A CD or USB). I don't think you will have to re-format your entire computer, though.

I wish I could give you a clear step-by-step tutorial, but I don't work with system maintenance enough to write an entire step-by-step tutorial by memory alone, but it's pretty easy to find.

I hope this helps.